# Unable to save entity while using CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony

I have an `Article` entity and I'm adding multiple categories to it dynamically. For that, I created a `CollectionType` field in the Article form. I'm able to add multiple categories in the frontend but when I save the Article I'm getting the following error.

`Error 500: Expected argument of type "MyBundle\Entity\Category", "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given`

Also please note that I'm adding categories to the `Article` dynamically, I have an add another button in the frontend for adding more categories to `Article`.

I have the following code:

`Article.php`

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Article {
    /**
     * @var Collection|Category[]
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Category")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCategories(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->category->contains($category)) {
            $this->category->add($category);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`Category.php`

```
namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class Category {

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return Tenant
     */
    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return  $this;
    }
}
```

`CategoryType.php`

```
namespace MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use MyBundle\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Category::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name'
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ArticleType.php`

```
namespace MyBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use MyBundle\Entity\Article;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('category', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Article',
            'role_repo' => null,
            'mode' => null,
            'article_entity' => null,
            'languages' => [],
            'payment_terms' => []
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired('article_repo');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'mybundle_article_entity';
    }
}
```

I have the following code in my `ArticleController.php`

```
public function addArticleAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var AdminAccount $admin */
    $admin = $this->getUser();
    $article = new Article(Editor::is($admin->getId())->at(self::class));
    $form = $this->createForm(
        'MyBundle\Form\ArticleType',
        $article,
        [
            'languages' => array_flip(Languages::getLanguages()),
            'payment_terms' => array_flip(PaymentTerms::getTermOptions()),
            'mode' => 'add',
            'article_entity_repo' => null
        ]
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_article');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/article/add.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

I have the following code in my template `add.html.twig`

```
<h3>Articles</h3>
<ul class="category" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.category.vars.prototype.name)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {% for category in form.category %}
        <li>{{ form_row(category.name) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm able to save the Article if I change my `setCategories` in `Article` entity

```
/**
 * @param ArrayCollection $category
 * @return Article
 */
public function setCategories(ArrayCollection $category): self
{
    foreach($category as $_category) {
        if (!$this->category->contains($_category['name'])) {
            $this->category->add($_category['name']);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But I don't think this is the best approach

Comment: Not clear of you got this sorted or not.  $builder->add('category' implies that your article has a get/setCategory methods which indeed it does.  So that is what is being used.  You should of course have get/setCategorys() along with $builder->add('categorys'

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ManyToMany relation, you article has a collection of categories.
Don't forget to put plural everywhere. So your setCategories should take a collection as an argument and set it. Then create an addCategory() and removeCategory methods.

If I'm correct you don't create the categories at the same time than the article, right ? So you don't need a collectiontype but an EntityType. If I'm wrong then you do need a collectiontype but in CategoryType, you don't have an EntityType but a TextType.

Comment: Yes it is `setCategories`, also I need `collectiontype` because I'm dynamically adding categories to the `Article`, like I have an `add another` button in the form to add categories. sorry, the actual code is not about Articles and categories.

Comment: Yes it is working like that but unable to save the entity because of that error

Comment: I'm talking about with the newly added add and remove methods